# Get time between two dates works for days and hours, but not minutes or seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm asking the user for two dates, one more recent, and one in the future.

My script should be able to return days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

It's successfully returning days and hours, but returns 0 for both minutes and seconds, what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!!

```
function calcTime()
{
  var userYearCurrent = parseInt(prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)","Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021"));
  var userMonthCurrent = parseInt(prompt("Enter a month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name","Enter a month ex: 11, November"));
  var userDayCurrent = parseInt(prompt("Enter a day of The month in mumbers(1-31)","Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21"));
  var userTimeCurrent = parseInt(prompt("Enter a time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)","Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time"));


  var userYearFuture = parseInt(prompt("Enter a FUTURE year in numbers(2019)","Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021"));
  var userMonthFuture = parseInt(prompt("Enter a FUTURE month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name","Enter a month ex: 11, November"));
  var userDayFuture = parseInt(prompt("Enter a FUTURE day of The month in mumbers(1-31)","Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21"));
  var userTimeFuture = parseInt(prompt("Enter a FUTURE time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)","Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time"));


var dateCurrent = new Date(userYearCurrent, userMonthCurrent, userDayCurrent, userTimeCurrent);
var dateFuture = new Date(userYearFuture, userMonthFuture, userDayFuture, userTimeFuture);

var mathSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime()  - dateCurrent.getTime()) / 1000;

var days = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 86400);
mathSeconds -= days * 86400;

var hours = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 3600) % 24;
mathSeconds -= hours * 3600;

var minutes = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 60) % 60;
mathSeconds -= minutes * 60;

var seconds = mathSeconds;

document.getElementById("time2").innerHTML = "Time between your two dates: " + days + " Days: " + hours + " Hours: " + minutes + " Minutes: " + seconds + " Seconds";
}
```

Comment: What do you think `parseInt('2:05:30')` will return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are calling something like `parseInt('2:05:30')` which won't give you what you need.  You need to parse each piece out individually, then pass hours, minutes, and seconds to each `Date` constructor as individual parameters.  See below (I've removed the prompts and added static values for sake of this example):

```js
function promptTime()
{
    var userYearCurrent = 2019;
    var userMonthCurrent = 10;
    var userDayCurrent = 2;
    var userTimeStringCurrent = '2:05:23';
    var userTimeStringCurrentParts = userTimeStringCurrent.split(':');
    if (userTimeStringCurrentParts.length === 2) {
        userTimeStringCurrentParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
    }
    var userHoursCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[0]);
    var userMinutesCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[1]);
    var userSecondsCurrent = parseInt(userTimeStringCurrentParts[2]);


    var userYearFuture = 2021;
    var userMonthFuture = 8;
    var userDayFuture = 14;
    var userTimeStringFuture = '6:37';
    var userTimeStringFutureParts = userTimeStringFuture.split(':');
    if (userTimeStringFutureParts.length === 2) {
        userTimeStringFutureParts.push('00'); // empty seconds
    }
    var userHoursFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[0]);
    var userMinutesFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[1]);
    var userSecondsFuture = parseInt(userTimeStringFutureParts[2]);


    var dateCurrent = new Date(userYearCurrent, userMonthCurrent, userDayCurrent, userHoursCurrent, userMinutesCurrent, userSecondsCurrent);
    var dateFuture = new Date(userYearFuture, userMonthFuture, userDayFuture, userHoursFuture, userMinutesFuture, userSecondsFuture);
    
    console.log(calcTime(dateCurrent, dateFuture));
}

function calcTime(dateCurrent, dateFuture)
{
    var mathSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime()  - dateCurrent.getTime()) / 1000;

    var days = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 86400);
    mathSeconds -= days * 86400;

    var hours = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 3600) % 24;
    mathSeconds -= hours * 3600;

    var minutes = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 60) % 60;
    mathSeconds -= minutes * 60;

    var seconds = mathSeconds;

    return "Time between your two dates: " + days + " Days: " + hours + " Hours: " + minutes + " Minutes: " + seconds + " Seconds";
}

promptTime();
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! What's the best way to add and structure two arguments to the function? For example function calcTime(current, future)

That way I could use the function in other code. How would I pass the arguments in as well? ex: calcTime('2019' '11' '30' '02' '5' '50', '2020' '11' '30' '02' '55' '50'); year, day, hour, minute, seconds

Comment: @Tman sure, see my edited answer.  I separated out the calculating of the time from the prompting of the user.

Answer (score 0):

For your example take the date constructor argument as `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` as exactly

```js
function calcTime(current, future) {
  var userYearCurrent = (current[0] || prompt("Enter a year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021"));
  var userMonthCurrent = (current[1] || prompt("Enter a month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name", "Enter a month ex: 11, November"));
  var userDayCurrent = (current[2] || prompt("Enter a day of The month in mumbers(1-31)", "Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21"));
  var userTimeCurrent = (current[3] || prompt("Enter a time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)", "Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time"));


  var userYearFuture = (future[0] || prompt("Enter a FUTURE year in numbers(2019)", "Enter a year ex: 2019, 2020, 2021"));
  var userMonthFuture = (future[1] || prompt("Enter a FUTURE month in numbers(1-12), or type a month name", "Enter a month ex: 11, November"));
  var userDayFuture = (future[2] || prompt("Enter a FUTURE day of The month in mumbers(1-31)", "Enter a day of the month ex: 14, 21"));
  var userTimeFuture = (future[3] || prompt("Enter a FUTURE time (2:05) or if seconds are needed(2:05:30)", "Enter a time of day ex: 11:15, do not use military time"));


  var dateCurrent = new Date(`${userYearCurrent}-${userMonthCurrent}-${userDayCurrent}T${userTimeCurrent}`);
  var dateFuture = new Date(`${userYearFuture}-${userMonthFuture}-${userDayFuture}T${userTimeFuture}`);

  var mathSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture.getTime() - dateCurrent.getTime()) / 1000;
  var days = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 86400);
  mathSeconds -= days * 86400;
  var hours = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 3600) % 24;
  mathSeconds -= hours * 3600;
  var minutes = Math.floor(mathSeconds / 60) % 60;
  mathSeconds -= minutes * 60;
  var seconds = mathSeconds;

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time between your two dates: " + days + " Days: " + hours + " Hours: " + minutes + " Minutes: " + seconds + " Seconds";
}

calcTime(['2019', '01', '11', '02:15:06'], ['2020', '09', '06', '17:45:26'])
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```